# Is the Java 8 Grammar still a LALR(1) grammar?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, parsers, java, lr-k

As I found out here: http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/howto/generate%20parser/generateParser.html , the Java Version of 2005 (might be Java 6, I'm not sure) is a LALR(1) grammar. However, I couldn't find out if the Java 8 grammar still is a LALR one. I found some Java 8 grammar on GitHub (https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java8/Java8.g4 ), however, I couldn't parse this file with jikespg like they did on the eclipse site I linked above. Is there another tool which I can try out?

Comment: Requests for tools are certainly off-topic. Community opinions on the title question?